# How to stay on the current page when change language?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resources, multilingual

I have an ASP.NET MVC web project supporting multiple languages. I used resources for the project. It is working well. But I have a problem. When I changed the language, it is always redirected to the home page.  How to stay on the current page when changing the language?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using language changer button action (`ChangeLanguage ActionResult`(or some other name) )your return value is should be some like this:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
```

change that that with this:

```
return Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);
```

this provides return to the current page.